# Secure store keys in browser (React)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, web, token, store

How to secure store keys in browser (for example in React)? Because sessionStorage and localStorage are vulnerable if XSS. The condition is using Cookies in Set-Cookie and token in sessionStorage is not good. Maybe exists some auth protocols which refreshes token every request (based on before requests, like Noise protocols logic)?